# Loading shapefile data into L.shapefile says nodebuffer is not supported by this platform

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, javascript, node-js, attribute-file-reader

I am having a shapefile that is converted to a Base64 string. I am converting it to a file and then trying to convert to arrayBuffer using '`FileReader`' to fit the data to match (L.shapefile)
https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile

*EDIT*: I fixed the previous problem, the current problem is the data (ArrayBuffer) added to leaflet.shapefile which returns the error.

Or if you got the zip some other way (like the File API) then with the arrayBuffer you can call

```
const geojson = await shp(buffer);
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shpjs

I tried working in this direction to fit the shapefile into L.shapefile as follows:

```js
import * as L from "leaflet";
import * as shp from "shpjs";

const l1 = require('../../assets/leaflet.shpfile.js');

export class Tab7Page {

  map: L.Map
  msgCheck: boolean;
  

  //Global variables
  geojson_data = '';

async ngOnInit() {

var shape_data = "data:application/zip;base64,UEsDBAoAAAAAAHZwplQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHAAAAbGF5ZXJzL1BLAwQKAAAAAAB2cKZUD7eKbDwBAAA8AQAAEgAAAGxheWVycy9QT0xZR09OLnNocAAAJwoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJ7oAwAABQAAAAAAAFCyGiBAeNAJLjeZSEAAAACYlB0gQMAkzNp mUhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAUAAAAAAABQshogQHjQCS43mUhAAAAAmJQdIEDAJMzafplIQAEAAAAKAAAAAAAAAAAAAJjEGiBAwCTM2n6ZSEAAAABQshogQKOtBVtUmUhAAAAAeLYbIEC8k8/CPplIQAAAABBpHCBAsUVS7DyZSED/// v9RwgQMXhbjg/mUhAAAAA6IAdIEB40AkuN5lIQAAAAJiUHSBAeeTrB2mZSEAAAACo7hwgQFKQcddwmUhAAAAAcNwbIEDbe339cZlIQAAAAJjEGiBAwCTM2n6ZSEBQSwMECgAAAAAAdnCmVObu5cZsAAAAbAAAABIAAABsYXllcnMvUE9MWUdPTi5zaHgAACcKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA26AMAAAUAAAAAAABQshogQHjQCS43mUhAAAAAmJQdIEDAJMzafplIQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMgAAAGhQSwMECgAAAAAAdnCmVGt60SP0AgAA9AIAABIAAABsYXllcnMvUE9MWUdPTi5kYmYDegQGAQAAAMEAMwIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHN0cm9rZQAAAAAAQwAAAAD AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAc3Ryb2tlLXcAAABOAAAAABIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABzdHJva2UtbwAAAE4AAAAAEgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGZpbGwAAAAAAAAAQwAAAAD AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZmlsbC1vcGEAAABOAAAAABIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAICNjNWQ1NzMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAyICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAxI2RiZDc5MCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAwLhpQSwMECgAAAAAAdnCmVOPBUWqPAAAAjwAAABIAAABsYXllcnMvUE9MWUdPTi5wcmpHRU9HQ1NbIkdDU19XR1NfMTk4NCIsREFUVU1bIkRfV0dTXzE5ODQiLFNQSEVST0lEWyJXR1NfMTk4NCIsNjM3ODEzNywyOTguMjU3MjIzNTYzXV0sUFJJTUVNWyJHcmVlbndpY2giLDBdLFVOSVRbIkRlZ3JlZSIsMC4wMTc0NTMyOTI1MTk5NDMyOTVdXVBLAQIUAAoAAAAAAHZwplQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAABsYXllcnMvUEsBAhQACgAAAAAAdnCmVA 3imw8AQAAPAEAABIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJQAAAGxheWVycy9QT0xZR09OLnNocFBLAQIUAAoAAAAAAHZwplTm7uXGbAAAAGwAAAASAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJEBAABsYXllcnMvUE9MWUdPTi5zaHhQSwECFAAKAAAAAAB2cKZUa3rRI/QCAAD0AgAAEgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAtAgAAbGF5ZXJzL1BPTFlHT04uZGJmUEsBAhQACgAAAAAAdnCmVOPBUWqPAAAAjwAAABIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUQUAAGxheWVycy9QT0xZR09OLnByalBLBQYAAAAABQAFADUBAAAQBgAAAAA="
var shape_fileName = "TestFile"
var reader = new FileReader();
var file = this.dataURLtoFile(shape_data,shape_fileName);
console.log("File Info...", file);
this.handleZipFile(file);

this.map = L.map("map", {
  center: [49.7, 8.12],
  zoom: 15,
  renderer: L.canvas(),
});

L.tileLayer(
  "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
  {
    // maxZoom: 12,
    attribution:
      "Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community",
  }
).addTo(this.map);

// this.map.setView(layer.getBounds()['_northEast'], 14);

setTimeout(() => {
  this.map.invalidateSize();
}, 1);

}
 handleZipFile(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      if (reader.readyState != 2 || reader.error){
        console.error("thats the error side");
        return;
      } else {
        console.log("Success npw shaping layers..");
        shp(reader.result).then(function (geojson) {    //More info: https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js
          l1.shapefile(geojson).addTo(this.map);//More info: https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile
          
        });
      }
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }

dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {

    var decodebase64 = "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";
    var bstr1 = atob(decodebase64);
    console.log("Byte sting", bstr1);
    var arr = dataurl.split(','),
        mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(decodebase64), 
        n = bstr.length, 
        u8arr = new Uint8Array(n); 
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
}
```

I just get a map with the below error has informed. I am not sure whether i am using the `leaflet.shapefile` correctly.

[image]
[image]

*EDIT*: As per comments from `TomazicM` i installed buffer and updated `polyfill.ts` and now I get the following error.

[image]

Comment: That helped me answering to use FileReader with onload. The current problem is handling the converted Bse64 URL to file which i use with `leaflet.shapefile` package. I am not sure whether I am using it right. The Layers of the shapefile is not inserted. If i change the data to geojson, i get the layer on the map. However i need to use the shapefile base64 data for my usecase.

Comment: Converting a shapefile to a base64 string is not the usual way that GIS people handle shapefiles (not the least because a "shapefile" is actually at least three files, and it doesn't make sense to base64-encode only one of them). It seems you're doing something exotic, and that isn't working for you, which increases the chance that this is an XY problem, and it's your solution that's faulty, not your implementation of that solution.

Comment: @Vince, Thanks for your suggestion. I am really new to this, hence I have no proper lead. The reason I am trying with base64 string is, that the shapefile uploaded from end-user is available to me in that format. I did try to convert to `base64 to arraybuffer` and feed it to `shp(buffer)` but this didnt work. Later i tried converting  `base64 to a file` and use it as mentioned above, similar to a regular file uplaod. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: How should I go ahead solving this problem, let's say you have got a "base64 zip file data" how would you transform it to fit in `L.shapefile` or `shp(buffer)`?

Comment: This might help with your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997027/uncaught-error-nodebuffer-is-not-supported-by-this-browser

Comment: @TomazicM I get the following error as mentioned in `EDIT`.

Comment: I would say this is more a question for StackOverflow site now, try there.